# ReactJS resource paths of built files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have a ReactJS project that produce static files for serving after `npm run build`. These files are an `index.html`, `main.ef19974a.js` and `main.f06643f6.css`.

The `html` file has references to each of these other files but as absolute paths. This means that when the client is served the `html` file, it tries to search for `/static/js/main.ef19974a.js` at the host machine rather than `static/js/main.ef19974a.js` from the same directory as the `index.html` file being served up.

Is there a way to make React create relative path references in the build step or allow us to provide the working directory?

A workaround that worked temporarily was to manually modify the resulting `index.html` file to reference the `js` and `css` files but fails when I include other resources such as images that are not referenced from `index.html` and defaults back to absolute paths for those files.

Comment: Add `"homepage": "/folder"` to your `package.json` (for me, this is stated in the terminal right when the building process has finished)

Comment: @ChrisG Perfect! Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the folder that will contain `index.html` in your `package.json` using the `homepage` key:

```
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
    },

    "homepage": "/myapp",   // website will be hosted at http://hostname/myapp

    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "toolbox": "react-toolbox-themr",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    ...
```